# How to turn website into web app

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications

I have  a pure HTML, CSS and JS website (built exclusively for iPad all the sizes etc. are in pixels and viewing it on a mac the whole site appears iPad size in the top left corner of the screen) but I want to turn it into an actual app that can go onto an iPad, and I also do not want to upload it to the app store.

Answer (score 1):

An app that is to be installed onto an iOS device must be downloaded from the app store.

However, you can "add to home screen" when they view your site. This will add an icon for your site on their iOS device's home screen which kind of looks like an app but it is just a Safari bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actual application you would need to do it in Xcode and upload it to the AppStore or for Enterprise & Ad-Hoc. Apple doesn't approve applications that consist out of webpages.

In Safari, add the website to Home Screen then give it a title. Safari generates the icon from the `favicon` details in your `<head>` tag and the title from your `<title>` tag.

[image]